# PHP - Upload picture and display on page

Tags: php, html

The following code allows me to upload pictures (using a html form) to a directory on my server.

```
<?php 

    $target = "http://www.mockcourt.org.uk/user/htdocs/pics/2012/";
    $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']); 
    $ok=1; 

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
    {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
    }
?>
```

Is there any way to modify it so that it will add the pictures to a html page instead?

Thanks

Comment: Select your text, then hit Ctrl+K to **indent the whole block of text by four spaces** to make it a code block. The individual back ticks around each line make it unreadable!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well after you upload it, you can use javascript to put it on the html page.

I'm not quite sure what your question is, though

**EDIT:**

So, html form on your page:

```
<form action="imageUpload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target"  onsubmit="jupload();"  id="form1" >
    <div style="visibility:'hidden';" class="imageholder"> <!-- a gif image to show that the process wasn't finished -->
    </div>
    <input type="file" name="imgfile" /> 
    <input type="submit" name="uploadButton" class="upbtn" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Javascript(JQUERY) code for the upload and image add:

```
function jupload()
{
    $(".imageholder").append('<img src="./images/loading.gif">');
}

function juploadstop(result)
{
    if(result==0)
    {
        $(".imageholder").html("");

    }
    // the result will be the path to the image
    else if(result!=0)
    {
        $(".imageholder").html("");
        // imageplace is the class of the div where you want to add the image  
        $(".imageplace").append("<img src='"+result+"'>");
    }   
}
```

php code:

```
<?php
    $target = "http://www.mockcourt.org.uk/user/htdocs/pics/2012/";
    $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 
    $ok=1; 

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
    {
        $result=$target;
    } 
    else
    {
        $result=0;
    }
?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.top.window.juploadstop(<?php echo $result; ?>);
</script>
```

Comment: I would like a scrpit that allows users to upload a picture and it automatically places the picture on to a page. If there are pictures on it will add the new picture to the page

Comment: you can use uploadify http://www.uploadify.com/demos/ and once uploaded you can show it to html page

Comment: I hope it helps, though Rakesh Shetty's solution might just be faster and easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the form in HTML to submit the image.. make the submit button, not a submit button, but just a button.. e.g.

```
<input type='button' id='submit_form' value='upload' />
```

and in the javascript, use Ajax to submit the form and Jquery to display it in the web page

```
$('#submit_form')click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: path/phpfile.php,
    data: image_input_name
  });

//after submitting, get the url of the image form the server

  $('#div_to_display_image').html("<img src='path/image_file.jpg' alt='this' />");

});
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Adding the image to the dom should take place in a callback after the success response.  As it stands now, this will not work.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/