# PHP Echo Uploaded File Twice

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image-processing, upload

I have this PHP, AJAX, jQuery upload script that uploads a file on submit live and will display the image. I will paste the code for each below. My problem is that I want to display the image and then display the source code for the image. For example:

**This is a picture of the image** 
*(I cannot upload the actual image because I need a reputation of 10 on this website)*

```
<img src="tick.png" width="40" />
```

So the script shows the image then below it it also shows the code for the image. Please can somebody help me with this problem I will be so grateful! Any solution is welcome I don't mind what language the solution is written in.

**HTML Code**

```
<form action="processupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="UploadForm">
<table width="500" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>File : </td>
    <td><input name="ImageFile" type="file" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit"  id="SubmitButton" value="Upload" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**Ajax Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        //elements
        var progressbox     = $('#progressbox');
        var progressbar     = $('#progressbar');
        var statustxt       = $('#statustxt');
        var submitbutton    = $("#SubmitButton");
        var myform          = $("#UploadForm");
        var output          = $("#ImageOutput");
        var outputTwo       = $("#ImageCopy");
        var completed       = '0%';

                $(myform).ajaxForm({
                    beforeSend: function() { //brfore sending form
                        submitbutton.attr('disabled', ''); // disable upload button
                        statustxt.empty();
                        progressbox.slideDown(); //show progressbar
                        progressbar.width(completed); //initial value 0% of progressbar
                        statustxt.html(completed); //set status text
                        statustxt.css('color','#000'); //initial color of status text
                    },
                    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) { //on progress
                        progressbar.width(percentComplete + '%') //update progressbar percent complete
                        statustxt.html(percentComplete + '%'); //update status text
                        if(percentComplete>50)
                            {
                                statustxt.css('color','#fff'); //change status text to white after 50%
                            }
                        },
                    complete: function(response) { // on complete
                        output.html(response.responseText); //update element with received data
                        outputTwo.html(response.responseText); //update element with received data
                        myform.resetForm();  // reset form
                        submitbutton.removeAttr('disabled'); //enable submit button
                        progressbox.slideUp(); // hide progressbar
                    },
            });
        });
```

**PHP Code** (processupload.php)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
<?php
//ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//error_reporting(E_ALL);

if(isset($_POST))
{
     //Some Settings
    $BigImageMaxSize        = 300; //Image Maximum height or width
    $DestinationDirectory   = 'uploads/'; //Upload Directory ends with / (slash)
    $Quality                = 80;

    // check $_FILES['ImageFile'] array is not empty
    // "is_uploaded_file" Tells whether the file was uploaded via HTTP POST
    if(!isset($_FILES['ImageFile']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']))
    {
            die('Something went wrong with Upload!'); // output error when above checks fail.
    }

    // Random number for both file, will be added after image name
    $RandomNumber   = rand(0, 9999999999);

    // Elements (values) of $_FILES['ImageFile'] array
    //let's access these values by using their index position
    $ImageName      = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['ImageFile']['name']));
    $ImageSize      = $_FILES['ImageFile']['size']; // Obtain original image size
    $TempSrc        = $_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']; // Tmp name of image file stored in PHP tmp folder
    $ImageType      = $_FILES['ImageFile']['type']; //Obtain file type, returns "image/png", image/jpeg, text/plain etc.

    //Let's use $ImageType variable to check wheather uploaded file is supported.
    //We use PHP SWITCH statement to check valid image format, PHP SWITCH is similar to IF/ELSE statements
    //suitable if we want to compare the a variable with many different values




    switch(strtolower($ImageType))
    {
        case 'image/png':
            $CreatedImage =  imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']);
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $CreatedImage =  imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']);
            break;
        case 'image/jpeg':
        case 'image/pjpeg':
        case 'image/jpg':
            $CreatedImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']);
    }



    //PHP getimagesize() function returns height-width from image file stored in PHP tmp folder.
    //Let's get first two values from image, width and height. list assign values to $CurWidth,$CurHeight
    list($CurWidth,$CurHeight)=getimagesize($TempSrc);
    //Get file extension from Image name, this will be re-added after random name
    $ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
    $ImageExt = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);


    //remove extension from filename
    $ImageName      = preg_replace("/\.[^.\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName);

    //Construct a new image name (with random number added) for our new image.
    $NewImageName = 'IMG-'.$RandomNumber.'.'.$ImageExt;
    //set the Destination Image
    $DestRandImageName          = $DestinationDirectory.$NewImageName; //Name for Big Image

    //Resize image to our Specified Size by calling resizeImage function.
    if(resizeImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$BigImageMaxSize,$DestRandImageName,$CreatedImage,$Quality,$ImageType))
    {






        /*
        At this point we have succesfully resized and created thumbnail image
        We can render image to user's browser or store information in the database
        For demo, we are going to output results on browser.
        */

        //Get New Image Size
        list($ResizedWidth,$ResizedHeight)=getimagesize($DestRandImageName);

        $ImageURL = '<img src="uploads/'.$NewImageName.'" height="'.$ResizedHeight.'" width="'.$ResizedWidth.'">';

        echo $ImageURL;




    }else{
        die('Resize Error'); //output error
    }



}
// This function will proportionally resize image
function resizeImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$MaxSize,$DestFolder,$SrcImage,$Quality,$ImageType)
{
    //Check Image size is not 0
    if($CurWidth <= 0 || $CurHeight <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //Construct a proportional size of new image
    $ImageScale         = min($MaxSize/$CurWidth, $MaxSize/$CurHeight);
    $NewWidth           = ceil($ImageScale*$CurWidth);
    $NewHeight          = ceil($ImageScale*$CurHeight);

    if($CurWidth < $NewWidth || $CurHeight < $NewHeight)
    {
        $NewWidth = $CurWidth;
        $NewHeight = $CurHeight;
    }
    $NewCanves  = imagecreatetruecolor($NewWidth, $NewHeight);
    // Resize Image
    if(imagecopyresampled($NewCanves, $SrcImage,0, 0, 0, 0, $NewWidth, $NewHeight, $CurWidth, $CurHeight))
    {
        switch(strtolower($ImageType))
        {
            case 'image/png':
                imagepng($NewCanves,$DestFolder);
                break;
            case 'image/gif':
                imagegif($NewCanves,$DestFolder);
                break;
            case 'image/jpeg':
            case 'image/pjpeg':
                imagejpeg($NewCanves,$DestFolder,$Quality);
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    //Destroy image, frees up memory
    if(is_resource($NewCanves)) {imagedestroy($NewCanves);}
    return true;
    }
}
//This function corps image to create exact square images, no matter what its original size!
function cropImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$iSize,$DestFolder,$SrcImage,$Quality,$ImageType)
{
    //Check Image size is not 0
    if($CurWidth <= 0 || $CurHeight <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //abeautifulsite.net has excellent article about "Cropping an Image to Make Square"
    //http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2009/08/cropping-an-image-to-make-square-thumbnails-in-php/
    if($CurWidth>$CurHeight)
    {
        $y_offset = 0;
        $x_offset = ($CurWidth - $CurHeight) / 2;
        $square_size    = $CurWidth - ($x_offset * 2);
    }else{
        $x_offset = 0;
        $y_offset = ($CurHeight - $CurWidth) / 2;
        $square_size = $CurHeight - ($y_offset * 2);
    }

    $NewCanves  = imagecreatetruecolor($iSize, $iSize);
    if(imagecopyresampled($NewCanves, $SrcImage,0, 0, $x_offset, $y_offset, $iSize,     $iSize, $square_size, $square_size))
    {
        switch(strtolower($ImageType))
        {
            case 'image/png':
                imagepng($NewCanves,$DestFolder);
                break;
            case 'image/gif':
                imagegif($NewCanves,$DestFolder);
                break;
            case 'image/jpeg':
            case 'image/pjpeg':
                imagejpeg($NewCanves,$DestFolder,$Quality);
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    //Destroy image, frees up memory
    if(is_resource($NewCanves)) {imagedestroy($NewCanves);}
    return true;

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: *"I want to display the image and then display the source code for the image"* What do you mean by that exactly? I don't quite understand what you mean by "display the source code". Do you mean show the file name or to actually display `<img src="tick.png" width="40" />` ? You will need to be more precise and/or give an example of the type of output you would like to have.

Comment: Thank you for your response Fred. I would like to actually display the source code of the image so the whole `<img src="tick.png" width="40" />`. I am creating a webpage that allows the user to upload an image in a 'design view', then they can preview their image in the 'live view' of the page then I would use the source code of the image and place that into the 'code view' of the webpage. This is all on one webpage and the page cannot refresh.

Comment: You're welcome. Ok, let me see what I can come up with. And have a look at the answer(s) in your other posted question, it may be of help.

Comment: Okay Thank you, I have not found a solution on the other question that will work yet. I really appreciate your help I have been trying to work this out for days!

Comment: Have a look at this page, it may be of help. I don't quite know how to do it exactly, and then again it could be something that's so simple LOL! here is the link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_file_uploading.htm it shows `Sent file: <?php echo $_FILES['file']['name'];  ?>` and more info.

Comment: Also have a look at this question (and answers): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260867/php-upload-picture-and-display-on-page **yet** more specifically on that page is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11261125/1415724 which uses `window.top.window.juploadstop(<?php echo $result; ?>);` to echo the result(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You want to display a html source code to image link You should use php htmlentities() function
for example:

```
echo htmlentities('<img src="pathtoimage/img.jpg" />'); 
echo htmlentities('<img src="pathtoimage/img.jpg" />',ENT_COMPAT);
echo htmlentities('<img src="pathtoimage/img.jpg" />',ENT_COMPAT,'utf-8');
```

result is:

```
<img src="sourcetoimage/img.jpg" />
```

not an image view

Comment: That is fantastic thank you It has displayed the source code!!!! Please could you now tell me how I could display the source code and the image in two separate div tags when receiving the data from the PHP script using AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

To encode html in JQ  You can use:

```
$('object').text(value).html();
```

To decode :

```
$('object').html(value).text();
```