# How to place a thought bubble on top of an image CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a work project that entails getting an image from a user, and based on that image, place a thought bubble, or speech bubble on top of that image.I have to consider placement and all that, but I just want a working version first. I'm using the jQuery facial recognition library for the image but I can't find any info on how to get a bubble on the image.

Comment: please describe what have you tried or clarify what you need... btw, giving a -2 vote to a newbie or a beginner is terrible. at least she have asked.

Comment: this should be of interest to you; http://facedetection.jaysalvat.com/

Comment: giving +1 to a question that does meet the requirements is terrible too. @FarizLuqman

Comment: Consider adding an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to encourage better quality answers.

Comment: your question is very open ended, you need to narrow down what you need in order to help you better. How about give us a small version of your code that you can use to implement in your project? First of all how do you get the image from the user? Anything more specific about this bubble we should know about?

Comment: I just started this project today. I'm just trying to get a sense of other's perspectives, I haven't wrote code yet, I'm very new to front-end design so I came here for answers. I didn't realize that people were so touchy with rules here, I didn't know I was breaking any? Ridiculous. I'm getting the image 1 of 2 ways, either through Twitter OAUTH or import/export.

Comment: @CodingEnthusiast well now it's +4. Indeed it is an open ended question, but it is still relevant

Answer (score 6):

What about something like this.

You can place the image inside a `<div>` which has a `border-radius` of 50% and `overflow: hidden`. This will clip the image to a rounded shape.

Then, using the CSS pseudo elements `:before` and `:after`, you can create two thought bubble trails.

I also added a little animation to make the bubbles float.

```css
body {
   text-align: center;
}  
.bubble-inner {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: float 2s ease-in-out infinite;
}
.bubble img {
  display: block;  
  max-width: 100%;
}
.bubble {
  position: relative;    
  display: inline-block;

}
.bubble:before,
.bubble:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px 0px #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.bubble:after {
  padding: 40px;  
  bottom: -40px;
  left: 0;
  animation: float 2s ease-in-out 0.2s infinite;
}
.bubble:before {
  padding: 20px;  
  bottom: -60px;
  left: -20px;
  animation: float 2s ease-in-out 0.3 infinite;
}

@keyframes float {
    0% {transform: translate(0,0) scale(1,1);}
    50% {transform: translate(0px,10px) scale(1.05,1);}
    100% {transform: translate(0,0) scale(1,1);}
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble">
  <div class="bubble-inner">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-200-200-1.jpg" alt="Person" >
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your question leaves a very broad range of answers, I will give you the simplest approach to use here:

1. Getting an image from a user, assumptions:

   - Either you have your own way of getting the image from the user and do not need help in such implementation, but are able to produce this image in HTML in a manner remotely similar to the following:

   - Do not have your own way of getting an image. In that case you need help with any kind of implementation; which according to your tags: javascript/jquery/css/html allows for a wide variety, meaning I can provide with a very simple PHP alternative: [PHP Upload a picture and display on page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260867/php-upload-picture-and-display-on-page)
2. Getting a bubble on the image: very broad again, but considering we have CSS available (as well as being part of the tags) then I can easily refer you to a myriad of ways of getting this done (including the answers already provided here): [Speech bubble with a shadow](http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/ptbbS/). You would then use either pure CSS or Javascript in order to dynamically show the speech bubble on the image after the image has been successfully loaded onto the page.

HTML:

```
<span class="bubble">Speech bubble with a shadow</span>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: #d6d6d6;
    padding: 100px;
}

/* Speech bubble with a shadow */

.bubble {
    background-color: #fff0a0;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,.5), hsla(0,0%,100%,0));
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,.5), hsla(0,0%,100%,0));
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,.5), hsla(0,0%,100%,0));
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,.5), hsla(0,0%,100%,0));
    background-image:         linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,.5), hsla(0,0%,100%,0));
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px hsla(0,0%,100%,.5),
                3px 3px 0 hsla(0,0%,0%,.1);
    color: #333;
    display: inline-block;
    font: 16px/25px sans-serif;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px hsla(0,0%,100%,.5);
}
.bubble:after, .bubble:before {
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid #fff0a0;
    bottom: -25px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
}
.bubble:before {
    border-right: 25px solid hsla(0,0%,0%,.1);
    bottom: -28px;
    right: 22px;
}
```

3. What to worry about: custom work, at that point in time you should come back with more questions (and code please).

Regardless of how neat you wish to get this to work, you will not get a straight and exact answer from anyone unless we see more code from your side. That aside, I believe that starting simple and working up from there will take you a long way... good luck!